# Gson parsing problem with release version - incorrect string is returned

Tags: java, android, json, gson, release

Hi i've problem with the library Gson in a release version.

In practice, in the release version of my application, using the `new Gson().toJson(obj)` method an incorrect string is returned.

***The returned string is missing some field of my object. Is it possible that the release version needs some missing options?***

**Here are some useful information:**

- The `obj` is an instance of `ArrayList<MyClass>`
- I'm using `implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'`
- I'm using `Android Studio 3.5.1`

*MyClass is build like this:*

```
public class MyClass{

    @SerializedName("a")
    private String a;

    @SerializedName("b")
    private Integer b;

    @SerializedName("c")
    private String c;

    @SerializedName("d")
    private String d;

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    ...

}
```

**Example:**

```
MyClass example = new MyClass("a","b","c","d");

ArrayList<MyClass> listExample = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
listExample.add(example);

String strObj = new Gson().toJson(listExample);
```

*Current output:*

```
[ 
   { 
      "b":"b",
      "c":"c",
      "d":"d",
   }
]
```

*Expected output*

```
[ 
   { 
      "a":"a",
      "b":"b",
      "c":"c",
      "d":"d",
   }
]
```

**To reproduce the error just follow the github:**
https://github.com/Ciardini/error02

Comment: Could you show the whole `MyClass` with all methods and constructors?

Comment: @MichałZiober There is not much to it, MyClass have two constructor one empty and the other one with all fields. Like the example the class have all get and set methods, i prefer to not share the class because it has more than 50 fields. Today i'll try to recreate a small sample with the error and publish it on github.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In release build Android compiler shrink and optimize code [[see Android doc]](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code). R8 deletes some apparently useless information, that are necessary for Gson to serialize objects correctly. To prevent R8 from stripping this info, you need to add the following code to proguard-rules.pro file:

`-keep class com.giacomociardini.error02.entities.** { <fields>; }`

For other details you can refer to this example on official Gson [GitHub](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg) repo.

Comment: Actually works! Thanks a lot, I assumed that android decreases the file dimension, but I had no idea that rules existed to define what is and what is not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `@Expose` instend of `@SerializedName`

```
@Expose
public String a;
```

Comment: Like this `@SerializedName("a") @Expose private Integer a;` or `@Expose private Integer a;` is not working.

Answer (score 0):

<del>Apparently the `toString()` method inside the parsed class is needed to make the Gson library work.</del>

<del>I don't know why but if you know it you feel free to respond!</del>

Adding the `toString()` method is a little trick to add information to the release version. You should follow the correct way on how to do it and add pro-guard rules.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "MyClass{" +
            "a='" + a + '\'' +
            ", b='" + b + '\'' +
            ", c='" + c + '\'' +
            ", d='" + d + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in the inner classes of the Model.java class so I did this to the proguard.pro file of that project, Inner classes are defined with '$' in proguard so,

```
-keep class path_to_models.Models$MyClass { <fields>; }
```

In Android Studio 3.4, R8 is used by default for all projects by default so if you need to switch to proguard then:

android.enableR8 = false in gradle.properties; or
useProguard = true in your build.gradle.