# GSON: How to decode from json to Model ignoring an Object?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have a Model consisting in a main `Manager` class, which has some variables, for example `name` but also has a big object called `data`. For a special case I want to pass from json to Model with `Gson` but ignoring the `data` Object of the json (for the normal case I will decode completely all the objects of the json).

I need to do this **without anotations and without transient**, just adding a deserializing rule to exclude `Data` class in case I want to do it.

How can I specify ad decode time that I want to ignore a class?

My model:

```
public class Manager{
    String name;
    Data data;
}

public class Data{
    String dummy;
    String dummy2;
}
```

Json sample:

```
{"manager":{"name":"testname","data":{"dummy":"testname", "dummy2":"testname2"}}}
```

Code sample that decodes all:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
new GraphAdapterBuilder()
                .addType(Data.class)
                .addType(Manager.class)
                .registerOn(gsonBuilder);
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
Manager manager = gson.fromJson(json, Manager.class);
```

Comment: Register a type adapter which (somehow) is made aware of if it’s a ‘special case’ and then doesn’t do anything with the `data` field?

Comment: You need this in a release version?

Comment: And what is a special case? Can it change during program run? Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920740/remove-empty-collections-from-a-json-with-gson/ will help you (there a JSON was cleared from empty collections).

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately for you, I banged my head last week to sort out a derivative of what you're trying to achieve. So as i mention in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58974728/gson-parsing-problem-with-release-version-incorrect-string-is-returned?noredirect=1#comment104222067_58974728) there is a little trick in the release version that maybe suite what are you trying to do:

> Apparently the `toString()` method inside the parsed class is needed to
>   make the Gson library work.

The toString() method expose the class to the serialization.

Having said that if you use a release version and don't add any proguard rules you can use the following method to exclude data:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Manager{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'}';
}
```

Comment: OP wants to exclude `Data` class in case he wants to do it, so how you achieve this?

Comment: I've made some test, there are fully explained here https://github.com/Ciardini/error02

Comment: Basically when not including a field within the toString() method it will not be serialized into a signed release version.